# Reject dismiss event with $modalInstance in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modals in an angular js app and want to defer dismissing the modal window if a condition is true.  I can't seem to get this working.  I have a function in place for my $scope.close() function but this is regarding the default dismiss() behavior when clicking the bootstrap backdrop.

```
$modalInstance.result.catch ((event)->
    if event == 'backdrop click'
        console.log 'check condition and cancel dismiss'
    return
), (event) ->
    return
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent the user from closing the modal depending on some condition? If that is what you want, then this is the wrong place to put that code.

Comment: why aren't you checking in the function that calls the dismiss?

Comment: Yes, if a condition exists I want to cancel the modal dismiss function.

Comment: this is to override the default behavior when clicking the modal backdrop which just calls dismiss(), not from a function call

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'backdrop' option which can be set to true (default), false, or 'static' (exists but doesn't close the modal).
You can have a scope variable be the value of that option:

```
$scope.backdropOption = true; //or false or 'static'
$scope.open = function (size) {

  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    backdrop: $scope.backdropOption,
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function () {
    ...
  }, function () {
    ...
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks, I want to keep the backdrop enabled as dismissing the modal I just want to reject it if a certain variable is true